# How to set grid cursor can work in entire grid?

Tags: wpf, grid, cursor

I have a grid with 2 rows * 2 columns, and put a TextBlock in left-up cell(row=0, column=0). 
then I set Grid.Cursor = "Hand" in XAML. the hand-cursor displayed only when mouse over TextBlock. But I want to display the hand-cursor in entire grid.

How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Set the Background of the Grid to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The Cursor is only applying to the content area of the grid. Thus to get the cursor across the whole grid, fill it in.

This can be shown, by changing what grid cells the TextBlock is positioned in.